# Using python beautiful soup to make a list of all image urls from a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning `BeautifulSoup` and I want to make a list of all image urls from a webpage (https://www.kaggle.com/navoneel/brain-mri-images-for-brain-tumor-detection).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/navoneel/brain-mri-images-for-brain-tumor-detection/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The code above doesn't yield any image urls.

And when I `print(soup)`, I can't see any image urls either.

But when I right click on one of the images and manually copy the link, I find out the url starts with `https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/165566/377107/`.

So I try setting `url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/165566/377107/'` for the above code, but that doesn't yield any image urls either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not in the page source it is likely loaded in by Javascript. You could look at the Javascript to see where it is generated or alternatively if you are just using this to learn BeautifulSoup you get get the page source with [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). Selenium uses a Chromedriver so you will need to have a chromedriver in your repo. (extract from here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/92.0.4515.107/chromedriver_win32.zip). Where 92.0.4515.107 is the version you want, or the latest version , which you can see [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE))

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/navoneel/brain-mri-images-for-brain-tumor-detection/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# parse the soup as you normally would from here
```

If you go to Chrome Dev Tools you can see the requests to these images:
[image: Chrome Dev Tools].

If you click on one of these requests you can see these requests have some query string parameters which have values like `X-Goog-Signature` and `X-Goog-Algorithm`.[image: Query Strings].

To get this full URL you would need to replicate the POST requests to https://www.kaggle.com/requests/GetDataViewExternalRequest which returns a JSON object like so:

```json
{"result":{"dataView":{"type":"url","dataTable":null,"dataUrl":{"url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/165566/377107/no/1%20no.jpeg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256\u0026X-Goog-Credential=databundle-worker-v2%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210801%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request\u0026X-Goog-Date=20210801T194627Z\u0026X-Goog-Expires=345599\u0026X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host\u0026X-Goog-Signature=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","type":"image"},"dataRaw":null,"dataCase":"dataUrl"}},"wasSuccessful":true}
```

Which is easily parsed by a simple code like:

```py
r = request.post("https://www.kaggle.com/requests/GetDataViewExternalRequest", data=data)
url = r.json()["result"]["dataView"]["dataUrl"]
```

The hard bit will come at generating this data, something like this:

```py
data = {
    "verificationInfo": {
        "competitionId": None,
        "datasetId": 165566,
        "databundleVersionId": 391742,
        "datasetHashLink": None
    },
    "firestorePath": "hIPSqqCWJs6oriNI20r6/versions/kKBcaXwa0lr8cvBuOMna/directories/no/files/1 no.jpeg",
    "tableQuery": None
}
```

I would expect most of those values are static for this page, it's likely the `firestorePath` changes. From a very quick search, it looks like all those values are scrapeable from the page either using regex or BeautifulSoup.

The request also has some headers including `__requestverificationtoken` and `x-xsrf-token`. Which looks like they are there to validate your request, they may be scrapeable, they may not. But, they are equal in value. You would need to add these headers to your request as well. I recommend [this site](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to help with creating requests easily. You just need to check the requests and delete any values which are not constants.

In summary, it's not easy! Use selenium if speed is not an issue, use requests and work all this out if it is.

After all that, the best option is using their [API](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api) as Phorys said. It will be very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The scraper looks good so the problem usually is the server which try to protect itself from... the scrapers! `BeautifulSoup` is a great tool for scraping static pages hence the problem is when you need to **request** a page:

Pass a user-agent to your request

```
user_agent = # for example 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers={ "user-agent": user_agent})
```

If this doesn't work investigate the response (cookies, coding, ...)

```
response = requests.get(url)
for key, value in response.headers.items():
  print(key, ":", value)
```

If you want only links maybe this could be better

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True): # so you are sure the you don't get an error when retrieving the value
    print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would look into using Kaggle's official API to access the data. They don't seem particularly restrictive and once you have it figured out it should also be possible to upload solutions as well: https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api

Just to push you in the right direction:

"The Kaggle API and CLI tool provide easy ways to interact with Datasets on Kaggle. The commands available can make searching for and downloading Kaggle Datasets a seamless part of your data science workflow.

If you haven’t installed the Kaggle Python package needed to use the command line tool or generated an API token, check out the getting started steps first.

Some of the commands for interacting with Datasets via CLI include:"

```
kaggle datasets list -s [KEYWORD]: list datasets matching a search term
kaggle datasets download -d [DATASET]: download files associated with a dataset
```